# Streaming Media Server Software Recommendations?

Tags: streaming, media-center

I'm looking for some sort of streaming media service to try and set up a home-based radio/video site to stream over LAN and internet. Overlooking the potential issue of residential upload speed, I'm looking for some software to do this, along the lines of Server 2003's Windows Media Server, to create and schedule programs, etc. I've seen Windows Media Services 2008 is a potential contender, but I would prefer something that would run on a non-server OS, such as XP or 7, or if there are Linux distros that would work, too. Also, I'm not sure how to set up the port forwarding for WMS.

I've had a look at MythTV. I'm not sure if this is really what I'm after but having to compile something would put me off. XBMC is a bit better, more single-computer rather than streaming though.

Comment: Marked as community wiki, potentially subjective. Unsure if there are any subdomain.stackoverflow.com sites better suited so posted here. Also tags for both "stream" and "streaming" should probably be merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options for you.... [TVersity](http://tversity.com/) and [Orb](http://www.orb.com/). Both are windows apps but they run on non-server OS's